# What are the requirements for objects contained in vectors

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, stdvector

In Exceptional C++, Herb Sutter wrote about `auto_ptr`:

> The problem is that auto_ptr does not quite meet the requirements of a
>   type you can put into containers, because copies of auto_ptrs are not
>   equivalent.

The book was written with respect to C++03, and I wonder whether this is still valid as this code seems to compile perfectly under GCC 4.7.1:

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { }
    Foo( Foo&& ) { }
    Foo( Foo& ) = delete;
    Foo& operator= (Foo&&) { return *this; }
    Foo& operator= (Foo&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> bar;
    bar.push_back(Foo());
}
```

But accepting moveable-but-not-copyable objects could also be a GCC extension. I am not sure. What are the requirements for `std::vector` objects?

Comment: It is a bit complicated, because now the requirements depend on the operations you want to perform on the vector instance and which constructor you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to use `std::vector<Foo>::push_back()`, the type `Foo` needs to be `MoveInsertable` or `CopyInsertable` (23.2.1 [container.requirements.general] paragraph 13) according to 23.2.3 [sequence.rqmts] paragraph 16 (Table 101). Clearly, providing the `MoveInsertable` model requires that you use `push_back()` with an r-value, possibly obtained using `std::move(x)`. That is, you don't even need the move assignment operator to be able to use `std::vector<...>::push_back()`. I think not all standard libraries correctly take this latter part into account and delegate to `insert()`: delegating to `insert()` doesn't work according to the C++ 2011 standard because `insert()` also requires the type to be `MoveAssignable` or `CopyAssignable`.

Trying to search for `push_back` unfortunately fails to point to Table 101 for me because the name is split into `push_` and `back()` by a line break...

Comment: OK, what about using algorithms such as `std::sort` on the vector? Can I be assured that moveability is the only requirement?

Comment: @qdii: I was just answering the question what is required for using `push_back()`! Other operations (e.g., using `insert()`) have other requirements and/or have specific implications. You'd need to look at the requirements for the respective member functions and/or algorithms.